# Is it possible to advertise an mDNS service with invalid name / type?

Tags: python, swift, reverse-engineering, mdns, python-zeroconf

I'm trying to recreate some functionality of [NearDrop](https://github.com/grishka/NearDrop/tree/master), a MacOS app to interact with Android NearbyShare functionality.
Namely, I want to create a program that's visible in NearbyShare.
The repo has [a description of the NearbyShare protocol](https://github.com/grishka/NearDrop/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md) and says that to be visible to Android devices you must advertise an mDNS service with specific properties.
The domain must be empty, the type is `_FC9F5ED42C8A._tcp.`, and the name is set to a specific 10-byte sequence encoded in URL safe base 64.

I tried to replicate this in python 3.10 using the python-zeroconf library, but I get a `BadTypeInNameException`.

```
    name = bytes([
        0x23, # PCP
        *bytes("AAAA", 'utf-8'), # endpointID
        0xFC, 0x9F, 0x5E, # Service ID hash
        0, 0
    ])

    endpoint_info = bytes([
        0b00000110, # version: 000, visibility: 0 (visible), device type: 011 (3 = laptop), 0
        *([0x00]*16), # unknown purpose
        0b00000110, # name length 6
        *bytes('mycomp', 'utf-8')
    ])

    protocol_name = "_FC9F5ED42C8A._tcp.local."

    info = ServiceInfo(
        protocol_name,
        ''.join(chr(c) for c in urlsafe_b64encode(name)),
        addresses=[socket.inet_aton("127.0.0.1")],
        port=80,
        properties={'n': urlsafe_b64encode(endpoint_info)},
        server="ash-2.local.",
    )
```

I think according to the specification the name needs to end width the type and the type needs to end in `.local.`, or at least the python package enforces something like this.

What confuses me most is that [the original Swift implementation](https://github.com/grishka/NearDrop/blob/66bfba5b023ff5800db8e677eed8e4e035163507/NearbyShare/NearbyConnectionManager.swift#L201-L218) doesn't seem to have a problem with this.

Did I interpreted the description of the protocol wrongly? or do I need to somehow force different behavior from the python library?